# Importar Vue ou outros componentes em componentes filho

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Tenho uma aplicação em VueJs2, na qual tenho um app.js, aonde instâncio o Vue e faço os imports (Templates, plugins, etc). Acontece que alguns plugins/libs eu consigo utilizar normalmente dentro de componentes filho (axios, por exemplo), já outros eu preciso fazer o import/use novamente dentro do componente. Exemplo: Vuex.

**Meu app.js**

```
//Vue
import Vue from 'vue'

//Axios
import axios from 'axios'

//Vuex
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

... 


//Main
new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Nesse contexto eu consigo utilizar o axios dentro dos componentes, normalmente. Sem necessidade de "re-importar" dentro do componente. Ele fica global.

**Um componente qualquer** (importado no meu app.js e funcionando)

```
<script>
import BtnAction from './../helper/BtnAction.vue';
export default {
    ...
}
</script>
```

No contexto acima, se eu tentar usar um Vuex, eu não consegueria. Como já mencionado, eu conseguiria (e consigo) usar o axios ou outra lib.

**Dessa forma dá certo**

```
<script>
import BtnAction from './../helper/BtnAction.vue';
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default {
     ...
}
</script>
```

Obrigatóriamente preciso inserir o Vue, inclusive. Se eu só importar o Vuex, ele acusa erro na falta do Vue.

O Vuex é só um exemplo. Ocorre com outras libs. Estou tendo essa dificuldade e não quero re-importar os plugins/libs... a não ser que realmente esse seja o jeito certo (e gostaria de saber pq no app.js não fica global).

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passar sua *store* do Vuex na criação do app da mesma maneira que passa o router. Algo assim:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        propriedade: 'valor'
    },
    mutations: {
        // ...
    }
});

const app = new Vue({
    store // ou store: store
}).$mount('#app');
```

Depois, dentro de um método de componente, você pode se referir à store assim com `this.$store`.

Comment: Ótima resposta! Obrigado.

Comment: Só uma dúvida: vc diz "dentro de um método de componente" ... eu poderia utilizar uma store fora de um método (mounted, created, etc.) ?

Comment: Sim, de qualquer lugar onde você possa acessar o `this` do componente @MarcoGarcia

Answer (score 0):

Vue.use faz o plugin se torna "parte" do Vue, passando a ser global(Acredito que seja isso que acontece). Logo oq vc "usou" var estar disponivel na propria instancia do Vue.
No caso do Vuex voce pode acessar com this.$store
No caso do Router voce pode acessar com this.$router